# How do I modify a row with an auto increment field?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Why is this creating a new row at the bottom with this data instead of modifying that specified row?

```
$sql = "
UPDATE products SET
    productName = '$pname', 
    productDescription = '$pdes'
WHERE pID = '$pidmod'
";
```

`WHERE pID='$pidmod'` is the auto increment field.

Comment: Did you try to run the query from mysql?

Comment: Sure would be nice if more people would think about formatting their code so the others who are asked to help could more easily read it.

Comment: Can you run `SHOW TRIGGERS LIKE 'product' ;` to check if there are triggers?

Comment: @ypercube: no triggers I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `UPDATE` statement does **not** add rows - unless there are triggers involved.

Comment: ok thanks, thats all I needed to know, I must have an error somewhere.

Comment: @GregMcNulty: So, did you find how the rows where created? By some other code?

Comment: yes there was an error in the code and it was: not updating and then executing another statement adding it to the end.